# MassTransit and RabbitMQ with sticky sessions

Tags: masstransit

Is it possible to use sticky sessions for Request/Response using RabbitMQ as the transport under MassTransit?

I have the following working using Azure ServiceBus as a transport, but we'd like to remain compatible with RabbitMQ as a fallback?

On the producer:

```
cfg.Send<SessionRequest>(x =>
{
    x.UseSessionIdFormatter(context => context.Message.SessionId);
});
```

On the Consumer:

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(endpoint.Item1, e =>
{
    e.RequiresSession = true;
    e.ConfigureConsumer(context, endpoint.Item2);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RabbitMQ does not have anything comparable to Azure Service Bus sessions.